# Knockout.js and IE8

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-8, scrollbar

I have issue with ko bindings in IE8 (not emulation). Whenever I use mouse to scroll, click binding isn't fired, no reaction in knockout script. If I scroll using scroll-bar suplied by markup all works fine.

Binding on ul li a:

```
<a href="#" class="template-tooltip" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-placement="bottom" 
    data-container="form" 
    data-bind="text: $data, 
    attr: {title: $data}, 
    click: $root.templateSelected">
</a>
```

ko script:

```
self.templateSelected =
                function(data, event) {
                    $("#message-body").focus(); //breakpoint here
                    self.messageBody(data);
                    self.templateText(data);
                };
```

breakpoint is hit in IE 9+ by any scenario
breakpoint is not hit in IE8 if mouse scroll button is used to scroll list of templates.

Any ideas on what can possibly cause this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean when you say mouse to scroll as the binding is for a click?

Comment: using mouse wheel to scroll content kills bindings on content what was scrolled.